# Mathematica 12 hangs up with specific powers p at Solve[{5 ==z-(Abs[-q]+Abs[q]), 3==z-(Abs[3^p-q]+Abs[3^p + q])}, {z, q}]. What should I do?

Tags: equation-solving

I try the code

```
p = 7/22
Solve[{5 == z - (Abs[-q] + Abs[q]), 
   3 == z - (Abs[3^p - q] + Abs[3^p + q])}, {z, q}]
```

when `p=7/18` or `7/20` or `7/21` the program evaluates quickly, when `p` is `7/16`, `7/19` or `7/22` and a lot of the other values it starts an infinte loop running. Do you have the same problem on your Windows 10? Of course I can use Wolfram Alpha any time instead but what is Mathematica for then?

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag unless other users have confirmed that what you have is a bug.

Comment: Cannot confirm that behavior in 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro. For `p=7/16` MMA produces `{{z -> 3 + 2 3^(7/16), 
  q -> -\[Sqrt](1 - 2 3^(7/16) + 3^(7/8))}, {z -> 3 + 2 3^(7/16), 
  q -> \[Sqrt](1 - 2 3^(7/16) + 3^(7/8))}}` in few minutes.

Comment: However, for `p = 9/32;` MMA is running without any response for ages.

Comment: The above case crashed my comp in several dozen minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica 12.2 on windows 10.

it hangs when domain is `Complexes`  which is the default. This could be either a bug or a feature, I do not know.

But for a workaround meanwhile, you could use `Reals`. Compared to Maple, and it gives correct result.

```
p = 7/22;
eqs = {5 == z - (Abs[-q] + Abs[q]), 3 == z - (Abs[3^p - q] + Abs[3^p + q])};
Solve[eqs, {z, q}, Reals] // InputForm
```

[image]

```
N[%, 30]
{{z -> 5.83688221082530144500590077762, q -> 0.418441105412650722502950388812}, 
 {z -> 5.83688221082530144500590077762, q -> -0.418441105412650722502950388812}}
```

Maple:

```
restart;
p:=7/22;
[solve({5 = z - (abs(-q) + abs(q)), 3 = z - (abs(3^p - q) + abs(3^p + q))}, {z, q})];
```

gives

```
sol := [{q = 3^(7/22) - 1, z = 3 + 2*3^(7/22)}, 
        {q = -3^(7/22) + 1, z = 3 + 2*3^(7/22)}]

Digits:=30;
evalf(sol)

[{q = 0.41844110541265072250295038881, z = 5.83688221082530144500590077762}, 
 {q = -0.41844110541265072250295038881, z = 5.83688221082530144500590077762}]
```

So answer by Mathematica is correct for `p:=7/22`, it just hangs for some reason when domain is complex.

Comment: That system implies `z\[Element]Reals`. However, `q` may be a complex number. Therefore, `Solve[eqs, {z, q}, Reals]` is not equivalent to `Solve[eqs, {z, q}]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {5 == z - (Abs[-q] + Abs[q]),
   3 == z - (Abs[3^p - q] + Abs[3^p + q])};
```

Restricting the domain to [`Reals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html),

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {q, z}, Reals]
```

[image]

If the condition in the [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) is not satisfied the result is [`Undefined`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Undefined.html).

For the case of `p == 7/22`,

```
Select[sol /. p -> 7/22, FreeQ[#, Undefined] &]

(* {{q -> 1 - 3^(7/22), z -> 5 + 2 (-1 + 3^(7/22))}, {q -> -1 + 3^(7/22), 
  z -> 5 + 2 (-1 + 3^(7/22))}} *)

% // N

(* {{q -> -0.418441, z -> 5.83688}, {q -> 0.418441, z -> 5.83688}} *)
```

Comment: The next step `Solve[eqns, {z, q}]` performs `{{z -> 3 + Sqrt[(-(1/2) + 3^p)^2] + Sqrt[(1/2 + 3^p)^2], 
  q -> -(1/2)}, {z -> 
   3 + Sqrt[(-(1/2) + 3^p)^2] + Sqrt[(1/2 + 3^p)^2], 
  q -> 1/2}, {z -> 4 + Sqrt[(-1 + 2 3^p)^2], 
  q -> 1 - 3^p}, {z -> 4 + Sqrt[(-1 + 2 3^p)^2], 
  q -> -1 + 3^p}, {z -> 4 + Sqrt[(1 + 2 3^p)^2], 
  q -> -1 - 3^p}, {z -> 4 + Sqrt[(1 + 2 3^p)^2], q -> 1 + 3^p}}` in a moment.